# % not working as wildcard for ActiveRecord default_scope query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, wildcard, default-scope

I am using ActiveRecord in my Rails project and one of my classes looks like this:

```
class ServerModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  set_table_name "S985_947_MODELS_VW"
  set_primary_key "model_barcode"

  default_scope :conditions => ["FULLNAME like '\/IT INFRASTRUCTURE\/HARDWARE\/SERVER\/PHYSICAL\/%' OR FULLNAME like '\/IT INFRASTRUCTURE\/HARDWARE\/SERVER\/PHYSICAL\/%'"]

  acts_as_reportable
  acts_as_entity
end
```

My default_scope method returns a `malformed format string - %'` error. I think it is the `%` wildcard that causes all the trouble. I also tried without escaping the `/`, so that's not it...

Could you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to:

```
default_scope :conditions => ["FULLNAME like ? OR FULLNAME like ?", '\/IT INFRASTRUCTURE\/HARDWARE\/SERVER\/PHYSICAL\/%', '\/IT INFRASTRUCTURE\/HARDWARE\/SERVER\/PHYSICAL\/%']
```